# RAD Studio 11.1 Clear Recent Files List

Tags: delphi

Does anyone have any idea how to 'easily' clear the recent files list that appears in the Welcome screen of RAD Studio 11.1? To be honest, I'm staggered that I even have to ask this question after years of Embarcadero's development.

Comment: I don't have 11.1, but in 11.0 you can use File > Open Recent > Properties... > Clear.

Comment: It's still at the same place in 11.1.

Comment: And 11.2 and 11.3 - they probably won't change the location soon.

Answer (score 7):

Here's screen shots from RAD Studio 11.1

File-> Open Recent->  Properties...-> Clear

[image]

[image]